# "Background" tab missing in terminal profile settings

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors

I want to make my Terminal transparent. The setting need is in the profile settings dialog of the Terminal, in the "Background" tab. The problem is, that tab just isn't there with my Ubuntu:

Left is expected, right is what I have.

[image]

What to do?

edit: I should probably have mentioned that I run ubuntu 14.04 LTS in a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: What's the version of your gnome-terminal? `gnome-terminal --version`

Comment: Version: Gnome Terminal 3.10.2

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that I run ubuntu 14.04 LTS in a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=698544

Answer (score 0):

Since this feature is remove from gnome 3.7, there are some workaround in:

[https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ#How_can_I_make_the_terminal_transparent.3F)

> Since version 3.7 this option has been removed from the Preferences
>   dialogue. You can however still get the same effect by setting the
>   _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY X property, for example with the Devil's Pie or Devil's Pie II tools. E.g., set up Devil's Pie to start automatically
>   with the session, and create the file ~/.devilspie/gnome-terminal.ds
>   with these contents:
>
> (if   (matches (window_name) "gnome-terminal-window-*")   (opacity 90)
>   )
>
> You can also use this shell script (@nirbheek) that however only works for
>   existing terminal windows and not automatically for newly created
>   ones.

(There are some links in the main article.)

and I forked @nirbheek script, and changed it, so it only make current terminal transparent, if you are interested it's available at [github/setXtransparent](https://github.com/2i3r/setXtransparent). then you need to exec `setXtransparent` after running the terminal.