# background tab dissapeared in terminal profile preferences

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, transparency

Recently I tried to solve a problem with evince annotation removal feature
I update my version but this didn't solve the problem and I lost the transparency feature that was really handy to start to learn.

I've seen there is much problems with gnome and transparency and there is not clear answers to this problem.

I just want to get back this functionality I had when I installed Ubuntu, is this possible? Thank you.

GNOME Terminal 3.10.2
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

exact this same problem, no real answer, just a lot of controversy with gnome developers.
["Background" tab missing in terminal profile settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624407/background-tab-missing-in-terminal-profile-settings)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
It's just that this version of gnome-terminal doesn't have transparency.
I'm just purging the ppa for gnome and reinstalling from ubuntu repositories. I hope it will work.

[Did they just remove the Background settings for Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475935/did-they-just-remove-the-background-settings-for-terminal)

Done